# Not sure how to reset my paused stopwatch

Tags: android, reset, stopwatch

(I'm fairly new to coding) Well, I've come across a solution to my previous posts and figured out how to display milliseconds... However, i cant seem to get the paused instance to reset back to 00:00:00

I've tried a few ways such as mreset elapsedTime and setting the base as 00:00:00, but nothing seems to work! Any suggestions?

Here's the Java file:

```
package com.jackson.eason.stopwatch;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Chronometer;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private Button startButton;
    private Button pauseButton;
    private Button resetButton;
    private long startTime = 0L;
    private Handler myHandler = new Handler();
    long timeInMillies = 0L;
    long timeSwap = 0L;
    long finalTime = 0L;

    private TextView textTimer;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textTimer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textTimer);

        startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
        startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                myHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerMethod, 0);

            }
        });

        pauseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);
        pauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                timeSwap += timeInMillies;
                myHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerMethod);

            }
        });

       //Updated.... Still having errors with parenthesis
    resetButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reset);
    resetButton.setOnClickListener(SystemClock.setCurrentTimeMillis()
     timeInMillies = 0L);
    timeSwap = 0L;
    finalTime = 0L;




    }
    private Runnable updateTimerMethod = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            timeInMillies = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;
            finalTime = timeSwap + timeInMillies;

            int seconds = (int) (finalTime / 1000);
            int minutes = seconds / 60;
            seconds = seconds % 60;
            int milliseconds = (int) (finalTime % 1000);
            textTimer.setText("" + minutes + ":"
                    + String.format("%02d", seconds) + ":"
                    + String.format("%03d", milliseconds));
            myHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
        }

    };

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please don't use stack snippets for Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the section for your reset button, you need to include an onClick event and set the time swap to 0 in there. Something like this:

```
.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view){
            finalTime = 0;
            timeInMillis = 0L;
            timeSwap = 0L;
```

Answer (score 0):

in your resetButton action try setting all your values back to 0

Comment: Thanks, but tried setOnClickListener(SystemClock.setCurrentTimeMillis(00:00:00)); But it didn't work out, because i'm not sure how to word it..

Comment: but you values still need setting back to 0 if thats what you're usiing to show current time
 long timeInMillies = 0L;
    long timeSwap = 0L;
    long finalTime = 0L;

Comment: You mean like this?                                                                                                                          resetButton.setOnClickListener(SystemClock.setCurrentTimeMillis(00:00:00);
        long timeInMillies = 0L;
        long timeSwap = 0L;
        long finalTime = 0L;

Comment: yes like that but remove 'long' otherwise you're just creating a new values

Comment: Ok, thank you, everything is fine on the code, except for the part that says                                  setCurrentTimeMillis(00:00:00));            This has multiple errors regarding the semicolons and parenthesis... not sure whats wrong?

Comment: go compare your onclick listener on startButton with resetButton you mite spot any mistakes you made

Comment: I just tried that, but im not sure what to look for because they aren't alike.